# how to get Multiple dropdown with using jquery json

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, jquery-ui

Hello Guys i want to change state based upon the country and the city according to state. but i can not use ajax i want get only based on javascript and json array.

```
    <label>Country:</label><br/>
            <select onchange="getval(this)">
            <option value="">Select Country</option>
            <option value="india">India</option>
            <option value="america">America</option>
            </select>


        <select name="" id="">
            <option value="">Select State</option>
            <option value="india">Orissa</option>
            <option value="india">Telangan</option>
            <option value="america">USA</option>
            <option value="america">California</option>
        </select>



    <select name="" id="">
        <option value="">Select city</option>
        <option value="orissa">Nal</option>
        <option value="orissa">Mir</option>
        <option value="Telangan">Hyd</option>
        <option value="Telangan">Vija</option>
        <option value="america">KRK</option>
        <option value="america">MRK</option>
    </select>
```

How to change state based on country. and afterthat change city based on state using javascript and json only.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, I would assign IDs to each one. Seconds, you would want to examine the selection once the `change` event is executed. Could you provide a bit more clarity on what needs to happen?

Comment: Please check the below link http://demos.thesoftwareguy.in/multiple-dropdown-jquery-ajax-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking this under the guise of needing help, yet you mention an assignment in your comments. We're not here to do your homework for you.

Regardless, and for the benefit of others, here is a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/5781ygy8/

**HTML**

```
<div class="select_wrapper">
  <label>Country:</label>
  <select id="country">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">India</option>
    <option value="2">America</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="select_wrapper hidden">
  <label>State:</label>
  <select id="state">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1" data-country="1">Orissa</option>
    <option value="2" data-country="1">Telangan</option>
    <option value="3" data-country="2">California</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="select_wrapper hidden">
  <label>City:</label>
  <select id="city">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option data-state="1">Nal</option>
    <option data-state="1">Mir</option>
    <option data-state="2">Hyd</option>
    <option data-state="2">Vija</option>
    <option data-state="3">KRK</option>
    <option data-state="3">MRK</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.select_wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.select_wrapper label {
  display: block;
  margin: 3px auto;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $("#country").change(function() {
    console.log("INFO: Country Selected, ", $(this).val());
    var sel = $(this).val();
    $("#state").val("");
    $("#state option").hide();
    $("#city").val("");
    $("#city option").hide();
    $("#city").parent().addClass("hidden");
    if (sel === "0") {
      $("#state").val("");
      $("#state").parent().addClass("hidden");
      $("#city").val("");
      $("#city").parent().addClass("hidden");
      return false;
    }
    $("#state option[data-country!='" + sel + "']").hide();
    $("#state option[data-country='" + sel + "']").show();
    $("#state").parent().removeClass("hidden");
  });
  $("#state").change(function() {
    var sel = $(this).val();
    if (sel === "0") {
      $("#city").val(0);
      $("#city").parent().addClass("hidden");
      return false;
    }
    $("#city > option[data-state!='" + sel + "']").hide();
    $("#city > option[data-state='" + sel + "']").show();
    $("#city").parent().removeClass("hidden");
  });
});
```

Here is where I would normally explain each part, but since this is for your assignment, I suspect that this will all be very clear to a studied and learned individual as yourself.

Comment: I don't how to thank you Mr. Twisty you saved my time. Thank's a lot.